# Whitelist domains to test localhost configuration

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I currently run my plugin locally via localhost:8080. I am trying to test my set up in a server. Can we whitelist "*.revation.com" and "*.revation.dev" so that I can test serving our plugin on those servers?

I receive "Refused to frame 'https://dev.revation.dev/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self'"

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Plugin Framework - Restrictions](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/restrictions/) page:

> Content Security Policy (CSP)
>
> Banno Online applies a Content Security Policy (CSP) for enhanced security. The implication for plugins is that JavaScript and CSS handling are limited by what is allowed in the CSP.
>
> The CSP is dynamically updated when Redirect URIs are added to an External Application.
>
> If your JavaScript or CSS is denied by the CSP (e.g. because they are hosted by a different domain than what is configured for the plugin’s Card Face or Expanded View), then update the appropriate External Application with an additional Redirect URI which points to the domain where the JavaScript or CSS is hosted.

Therefore, you should update your plugin's External Application by adding the relevant URIs. Doing so will update the CSP for Banno Online.